# R storing quotation marks without backslash

Tags: r, string, post

I need to do a loop for a POST request.

The post looks something like this:

```
r <- POST(http://decentralization.gov.ua/graphql?query={community(id:"2"){title}})
```

And I need to replace the "2" for a an i (loop). The problem is that R scapes the quotation marks with a backslash, and the post function take those backslash as part of the address.

I have tried combining single and double quotes, sprintf() and dQuote()

The result is always the same:

```
"http://decentralization.gov.ua/graphql?query={community(id:\"i\"){title}}"
```

and I believe those backslashes are messing up the post request (status_code: 400).

Is there any way to store a string with quotation marks without the backslashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably paste the URL within every iteration. The following code worked for me:

```
for (i in 1:2) {
  url <- paste0('http://decentralization.gov.ua/graphql?query={community(id:"', i, '"){title}}')
  res <- httr::POST(url = url)
}
```

Comment: Everything works fine now, the problem seems to arrise when I query more than just the "tittle", I have reviewd all the code and it work now, thanks Jan.